# Polynomial ring, ideals and Spec

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, integral-domain

Morning everyone, I want some hint about this.

i) Determine all ideals of $\frac{\Bbb{R[X]}}{<X^3-1>}$ 
where **$R$** is real set

ii)Is $\frac{R[X]}{<X^3-1>}$ integral Domain

iii)Determine its Spectrum(Spec)

My Answers

i) ideals are the form of $\frac{P}{<X^3-1>}$ where $P$ contains $<X^3-1>$  but I don't know how to define **P**

Comment: Hint for (ii): $(X-1)(X^2+X+1)=X^3-1\sim0$

Comment: Use the relationship between ideals of a ring and ideals of its quotients.

Comment: Yeap but I begin to study it right now

Answer (score 1):

the ring $\Bbb{R}[X]$ is principal ring because $\Bbb{R}$ is a field.  the  ideal in this quotient are in the forme classes of $\langle P(X)\rangle =\langle P(X)\rangle +\langle X^3-1\rangle =\{S(X)P(X)+T(X)(X^3-1), S,T\in \Bbb{R}[X]\}$ and better we can represent this class by class of $\langle R(X)\rangle$  where $R(X)$ is the rest by
euclide division of $P(X)$ by $X^3-1$.

the polynomial $X^3-1$ is not prime because not irreducible so the ideal    $\langle X^3-1\rangle$ not prime and therefore the  quotient ring is not integre.

Let $J$ an ideal in the quotient the canonical projection asure that  $J$ is a class of $\langle P(X) \rangle$ where $ \langle X^3-1\rangle  \in \langle P(X)\rangle$   if  we loock , at the compositum of canonical projection $ \Bbb{R}[X]\twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{R}[X]/ \langle X^3-1\rangle\twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{R}[X]/ \langle X^3-1\rangle/J$, by isomorphisme theorem, we can say that J is prime in $\Bbb{R}[X]/ \langle X^3-1\rangle$  if and if $P$ is a irreducible  factor of $X^3-1$ that is $P=x-1$ or $ X^2+X+1$.

Comment: Very well, thanks so much

Comment: welcome; and good luck

Comment: DearAli, I want to know is what you came to $\Bbb{ R}[X] / \langle X^3-1 \rangle$  has
only two nontrivial ideals and the two non-trivial quotients are
integre.

Answer (score 0):

For i), it means $P$ is divisible by $X^3-1$. In other words: $P(1)=0\;$ and $\;P(\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}3})=0$.

ii) Hint: use the *Chinese remainder theorem*.

iii) Hint: think of the factorisation of $X^3-1$ into irreducible factors and use i).